# How can I write unit tests for classes using LocalBroadcastManager?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, localbroadcastmanager

Our normal way of writing unit tests is using **mocks** via Mockito. However, `LocalBroadcastManager`, for some unexplicable reason, is *final* - thus preventing Mockito from expanding it, which prevents us to `mock`/`spy` it...

--> How can I write unit tests for a class that contain LocalBroadcastManager?

I would for example like to check that when some conditions occur etc. certain broadcasts (containing specific extras) are sent out.

Answer (score 1):

Use PowerMock:

Run your test class with PowerMock:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) 
@PrepareForTest({LocalBroadcastManager.class})
```

Then where-ever in your test you want to mock the static method, do this:

```
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalBroadcastManager.class);
    LocalBroadcastManager instance = mock(LocalBroadcastManager.class);
PowerMockito.when(LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)).thenReturn(instance);
```

Comment: It trows me an error when I call PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalBroadcastManager.class):

Cannot subclass final class class android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager

Comment: Make sure you do this on top of your class: @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({LocalBroadcastManager.class})

Comment: That worked :D
Could you update the answer to make it more clear for others?
Thank you!